# How to log SSL handshake in node's https module

Tags: node.js, ssl, https

I have a server written in node which implements a secure two-way SSL web-server:

```
var https = require('https');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

var options {
  key: ...,
  cert: ...,
  ca: ...,
  requestCert: true,
  rejectUnauthorized: true
};
https.createServer(options, app).listen(port, host);
```

But for some unknown reason, the client fails to connect. So it would be great if I could get any logs on why the connection has failed.

So far, all the logs I can get come from `app` which is an express object.  But the problem is that when a connection is rejected due to a certificate issues, it does not reach express so I get no error logs. How can I get logs from `https` server?

Comment: Have you tried using `server.on('error')` to check if the error event is being fired? [See here](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_server_listen)

Comment: @dubonzi Now I did without any success. Thanks though.

Answer (score 15):

I've run into this problem as well and while I couldn't come up with a solution that logs all the errors within the `https` module, I was able to get it to log debug information by using:

```
NODE_DEBUG='tls,https' node server.js
```

This isn't ideal as it doesn't give you the exact error (eg: Bad SSL Handshake) and the related traceback, it does give you information like `TLS: onhandshakestart` which lets you figure out if there was an error if you can't find a corresponding `TLS: onhandshakeend` in the logs.

Comment: using this where?

Answer (score 7):

There is an option in the config for `createServer` called `enableTrace` that causes Node to print a ton of details about the handshake:

```
var options {
  key: ...,
  cert: ...,
  ca: ...,
  requestCert: true,
  rejectUnauthorized: true,
  enableTrace: true // Set this :)
};
```

See [the docs](https://nodejs.org/api/tls.html#tlscreateserveroptions-secureconnectionlistener) for more info.

Comment: This works very well. I saw "VERSION=UNKNOWN" and it stopped there and realised one client was set to http so it wasn't even beginning the handshake.